# where is confluent path on debian

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I installed confluent community platform [Manual Install using Systemd on Ubuntu and Debian](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install)

I can start:

```
sudo systemctl start confluent-zookeeper
sudo systemctl start confluent-kafka
```

...

but where is my confluent path?

I do not have confluent cli

please help

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem when setting up elastisearch for confluent. In my system /usr/bin acted as /bin and remaining set up was successfull . So try using /usr as path to confluent  if following Manual Install using Systemd on Ubuntu and Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install [Confluent CLI](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html):

```
curl -L https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /<path-to-directory>/bin
```

> Run this script to install the Confluent CLI. This command creates a
>   `bin` directory in your designated location (`<path-to-directory>/bin`).
>   The location must be in your `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`).